# communication between PHP and JS when a row is added in JS

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, select

I have a php code as shown below:

**Php code:**

```
<?php     
$output['house_sitting_date_yes_no']=$_POST['house_sitting_date_yes_no'];

if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json'));
}
?>

<?php if($data) { ?>
<form>
    <!-- Sitting Days START -->
    <div class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <!-- Yes/No START -->
        <div class="yes-no">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Yes/No</h4>
            <select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no" id="house-yes-no" style="height:24px;">
                <option value="nada" <?php if($data->{"house_sitting_date_yes_no"}=="nada"){echo 'selected';}?>>Please choose an option</option>
                <option value="yes" <?php if($data->{"house_sitting_date_yes_no"}=="yes"){echo 'selected';} ?>>Yes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Yes/No END -->
    </div>
    <!-- Sitting Days END -->
</form>
<? } else {
echo 'Cannot read JSON settings file';
}
?>
```

The above php code corresponds to the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3u4d072/2/embedded/result). In the fiddle, its adding a new row on click of a button in Javascript. 
I haven't included JS code in the above php code. 
*Add new row* button lets us add as many rows as we want. After adding we can enter **Yes** in the input box and then Save.

**Problem Statement:** 

I am facing one issue at this moment. When I am **adding new rows**, form do get saved but **newly added rows get deleted leaving back only one row (Date and Yes/No)**. 
I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that when we add new rows, it should have some values associated with it so that when we save the form newly added rows should stay 
there with their respectibve values.

When there is one row (when I am not adding new row), everything is pulled from the JSON and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Change the name in both select, the one already showing up and in the function house_sitting_date_yes_no[] and it will be send to the $_POST as array.

Comment: @miguelcalderons I am wondering if you can give me a pointer in an answer. Any help on that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Caution, you're opening yourself up to potential security issues with this code.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` when inserting arbitrary data into the context of HTML.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to make some alterations to both your HTML, JS and PHP for it to work properly. No communication is needed from JS to PHP. The form submission already works, right?

### Modify the `name` attribute value.

Because you have multiple `select` and `input` elements in your code you'll want to be able to send all of the values of these elements to the server. But because they all have the same `name` attribute values you'll need to make a modification to these values.

Add a `[]` to the end of the name. This enables PHP to read every `house_sitting_date_yes_no` as an array. That means that every, in this case, `select` field value on the page will be send to the server in the global `$_POST` variable.

Check the example below.

```
<select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no[]">
  ...
</select>
```

The name has a `[]` at the end to indicate that there will be multiple values under the same name of `house_sitting_date_yes_no`.

```
<?php
$_POST[ 'house_sitting_date_yes_no' ] // array( 'yes', 'no', 'nada' )
?>
```

On the serverside you can access these values like you normally would do. But in this case it is not a string but an array with multiple strings. One string for each, in this example, select field.

### An ID can only be used ONCE. Use classes instead.

Your `newRow` function creates a new row. Which is a perfect way to do it but the function also outputs elements with `id`'s. ID's have to be unique and cannot be on the page more than once.

Wherever the id's can be removed, remove them and use a class instead. Or make them unique like they should be.

### Storing the values in JSON

You were already on your way with this one with opening and decoding the JSON file. I assume you want your JSON to be updated with more data instead of overwriting the current data.

Since the data will be stored in *associative array* that is encoded to JSON it's possible to use [`array_merge_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) to combine these arrays and their values.

After combining the values encode the array back to JSON and use `file_put_contents` to save your file again.

```
$output = array();
$output['house_sitting_date'] = $_POST['house_sitting_date'];
$output['house_sitting_date_yes_no'] = $_POST['house_sitting_date_yes_no'];

$file_url = '../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_house.json';

if (file_exists($file_url)) {

  // Get current file.
  $current_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file_url));

  // Combine data if possible, or create a new data.
  if (is_array($current_data)) {
    $new_data = array_merge_recursive($current_data, $output);
  } else {
    $new_data = $output;
  }

  // Update the file with new data.
  $updated_data = json_encode($new_data);
  file_put_contents($file_url, $updated_data);
}
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: @NVRM I have edited my question. Hope it makes sense. The row which is added through script should have some values associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok from what I see in your code is the old way I used to do things when working with PHP

I used to mix PHP with HTML and Javascript which on a big projects makes things a lot harder to maintain and debug especially many years down the line .You end up with many if else statements that could complicate your code

As well as if the PHP server is hanging because of shared hosting traffic or latency at least the clients browser does not hang. XHR and Rest API's were the  Aha moment for me...

So I changed the way I worked with the web technologies and started working with rest API clients and separating my front end and back end technologies

Here is my suggestion

1. HTML Forms, XHR and Jasvascript posts to the rest PHP server for
   every onclick event (this keeps the browser fast and wont hang like a php page sometimes does when working with background service)
2. The server handles each request reads the JSON from the file and
   slots the new entry in then saves the file (PHP ONLY in the background)
3. Javascript then refreshes the JSON cache. At the end of the XHR request  display the dates page   (do this by adding keywords like async and await )

Here is the start..

Call this file post.PHP

```
        <?php
    // Headers
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

    if($_POST)
    {
    echo json_encode($_POST);
    //Open your Existing JSON file here and do the edits to append the new data 
    //Note weather your data passed or failed you have to respond back to the XHR request in the front end with json_encode...



    }else{

    echo json_encode(
            array('message' => 'Post  Created')
    );
    }



    ?>
```

Its the same as a rest client access point. This file is where you edit your json with the update ...

The snippet is the frontend with the XHR and a special technique to extract form data from a HTML form

```js
function rowAdd(event) {
        document.getElementById("rows")
          .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newRow());
    }
// Iterator to get allow unique for ID;s
let i =0 ;

      function newRow() {

            i++;
      return `
        <div id="default-node" class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
                <input type="date" id="house-sitting-date`+i+`" name="house_sitting_date`+i+`" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="yes-no">
                <select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no`+i+`" id="house-yes-no`+i+`" style="height:24px;">
                    <option value="nada" selected>Please choose an option</option>
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="no">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
      `
    }





let xtart = document.getElementById('xhrStart');


xtart.addEventListener('click',function(){console.log('Xstarted')

                // First iterate over the form and get all the form Values
                var element = {};
                var data = new FormData(theForm);

                // Display the key/value pairs
                for(var pair of data.entries()) {
                       // console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]);
                       element[ pair[0].toString() ] = pair[1];
                }
                console.log(element);


                // Time to send the control over to PHP to do its magic

                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.open('POST', 'post.php');
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");


                xhr.responseType = 'json';
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(element));
                //xhr.send();

                // the response is {"message": "Hello, world!"}
                xhr.onload = function() {
                  let responseObj = xhr.response;
                  alert(responseObj.message); // Hello, world!
};



});
```

```html
<h3 style="text-align:center;margin-top:45px;">Sitting Days</h3>
<div class="add-new-row-button">
    <input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add New Row" onclick="rowAdd()" />
</div>
<form id='theForm'>
<div id="rows">
    <div class="sitting-days" style="display:flex; justify-content:center; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px;">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
            <input type="date" id="house-sitting-date" name="house_sitting_date" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="yes-no">
            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Yes/No</h4>
            <select name="house_sitting_date_yes_no" id="house-yes-no" style="height:24px;">
                <option value="nada" selected>Please choose an option</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Submit' id='xhrStart'>
```

Note I gave the form an ID and created and iterator so each new  element in the form is unique

Here is the snippet ...

PHP leaves you also slightly in the dark about the weather data was received or not and using XHR allows you to easily see server responses with Google debugging tools ... Node JS , react and and all the other great technologies have used the same principals of rest api because it allot simpler and it makes debugging on chrome a breeze

Here is an image of the debug
[image]

Trust this helps and allows you to work far more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

echo "<div id='demo'></div>"; 

?> 

<script type="text/JavaScript"> 


// Function is called, return  

// value will end up in x 

var x = myFunction(11, 10);    

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; 


// Function returns the product of a and b 

function myFunction(a, b) { 

return a * b;              

} 

</script>
```

Comment: Answers should have explanations.